# Unable to get element of my pop up sign up

Tags: javascript, xpath, cypress, popupwindow, relative-locators

Cypress is not able to find the XPath or element location of the pop up sign up.
I want to enter email and password, confirm password and then enter. But I am unable to get the elements of these fields. Can someone please tell me how to take xpaths or locators of the pop up forms. I am attaching the link and image below for more clarity
https://birdhunt.bubbleapps.io/version-test/
[image]

Comment: Add the code you tried.

Comment: Xpath is hard to read. Which element are you trying to access?

Answer (score 2):

The xpath is valid, so it's likely you forgot to add the cypress-xpath add-in.

See the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/xpath)

> **Install with npm**
> `npm install -D @cypress/xpath`
>
> **Install with Yarn**
> `yarn add @cypress/xpath --dev`
>
> Then include in your project's support file
> `require('@cypress/xpath');`

But you are using `cy.get()` with an xpath expression, which should be obvious mistake.

Either use `cy.get('css-selector-here')` or use `cy.xpath('xpath-expression-here')`.

Answer (score 0):

To complete, you should use relative XPath expressions instead of absolute ones. In your case :

```
//input[@placeholder="Email"]
//input[@placeholder="Password"]
//input[@placeholder="Confirm password"]
```